# Console not reading input of user?

Tags: java, swing, console, console-application

I downloaded the source code of a java console app from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328417/Java-Console-apps-made-easy .
Source code for JavaConsole: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=328417

I downloaded the required files as i wanted to try my code on a custom made console. My code is:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Addnumbers extends JFrame{


 public static void main(String args[]){

  new JavaConsole();

  int x, y, z;
  System.out.println("Enter two numbers to be added ");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  x = in.nextInt();
  y = in.nextInt();
  z = x + y;
  System.out.println("Sum of entered numbers = "+z);



 }
}
```

The problem is that, when i run "Addnumbers", the console opens up and displays "Enter two numbers to be added " But when i type in 2 numbers, it doesn't do anything. Does the console source code have to be modified for that? The code works perfectly in the usual terminal on eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: Are STDIN and STDOUT automatically redirected to the Java Console, or you have to do this manually?

Comment: @FabioCarello have to do it manually.

Comment: Maybe you make a mistake doing it. Try to post the complete code of your console.

Comment: Why are you using both a GUI and command line interface?

Comment: i wanted to experiment with the GUI and see if it's possible to convert your code or call some methods for it to display on the GUI instead of the regular command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try including scanner.nextLine() at the end so that it reads the end of your System.in input (the numbers). This is seriously a rough crack at it.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
x = in.nextInt();
y = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
z = x + y;
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to that way..it still doesn't read the input though :(